# Xcode 7 AVFoundation Compiler error

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, xcode7

I have been struggling to compile my code which was working fine previously here is the error

[image]

Anybody having the same issue? it seems some issue in **AVFoundation** but dont know how to solve this Running Xcode 7.0.1

Comment: Most likely you edited your version of header files. Check if you made any changes.

Comment: No i havent made any changes it was working fine in xcode 6

Comment: Can you post some code ?

Comment: Code but i have used this at so many places

Comment: Can you use that exact code and open it on xcode 6 and build it successfully ?

Comment: Yes it builds sucess in xcode 6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90931/discussion-between-nicolas-s-and-hardik-shah).